# Short way to write conditional assignment in ObjC

Tags: objective-c

Does Objective-C have an even shorter way of writing this line of code?

```
 a = b ? b : c;
```

That is, a way to say, `a` is equal to `b` as long it is not `nil`, else `c`.  This is like Ruby's operator `||=`

Comment: Objective-C doesn't have a null-coalescing operator as far as I know.

Comment: I'm curious as much as anything - although for readability it would still be worth it for a line like:   self.nameTextField.text = (self.weConfig.title) ?  self.weConfig.title : @"";

Answer (score 102, accepted):

Does the following work for you:

```
a = b ? : c;
```

(This syntax is a GNU extension to C, so you might have to use the GCC and not LLVM - http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.2.3/gcc/Conditionals.html#Conditionals).

Comment: Wonderful :-) Missed null-coalescing coming back from C#. '?:' does the trick very nicely.

Comment: "This syntax is a GNU extension to C, so you might have to use the GCC and not LLVM" - that's not related to LLVM. It's just the optimizer + code generator. You wanted to say "clang"? Still not, clang implements almost all GNU extensions. (It's still a very bad idea to depend on GNU extensions, though.)

Comment: Awesome! Just in case anyone was paranoid like me, yes it evaluates b only once ;).

Comment: I like to use `a = b ?: c;` and pretend it's a single operator. Xcode supports this just fine.

Answer (score 2):

That's as short as you can get it in Objective-C! That's a nice little test you have there.

The only other short way I could come up with is as follows (I wouldn't recommend it for readability reasons and it isn't as short as yours!):

```
if (b) a = b; else a = c;
```