# How to allow NSMutableDictionary to accept 'nil' values?

Tags: objective-c

I have this statement:

```
 [custData setObject: [rs stringForColumnIndex:2]  forKey: @"email"];
```

where `[rs stringForColumnIndex:2]` obtained from a SQLite3 d/b has a value of `nil`.  The app crashes giving me the error:

```
NSCFDictionary setObject:forKey:]: attempt to insert nil value (key: email)'
```

Is there a way to prevent this? (like a setting for `NSMutableDictionary`?)

UPDATE:  this is what I finally did:

```
[custData setObject: ([rs stringForColumnIndex:2] != nil? [rs stringForColumnIndex:2]:@"") forKey: @"email"];
```

Comment: That looks like a good solution to me.  @"" is a good way to maintain the placeholders for the keys when there is no valid value, otherwise you might have the same issue when you access the values for keys later.

Comment: As a shortcut: custData [@"email"] = [rs stringForColumnIndex:2] ?: @"";

Answer (score 39, accepted):

There is a non-`nil` object called [`NSNull`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNull_Class/Reference/Reference.html) that is built specifically to represent `nil`s in situations where "plain" `nil` is not acceptable. If you replace your `nil`s with `[NSNull null]` object, `NSDictionary` will take them. You would need to check for `NSNull` on the way out, though.

Note that this is important only when you must differentiate between a value not being set and a value being set to `nil`. If your code is such that it can *interpret* a missing value as `nil`, you do not need to use `NSNull` at all.

Comment: I'm setting values in a NSMutableDictionary so I can pass an array of data to a method (Objective-c).  As such, the method can handle the nil, but apparently the dictionary can't.  So there is no setting I can set to allow 'nil' keys, huh?  Probably would have to use a conditional operator?

Comment: @spokane-dude No, there is unfortunately no setting that would let you store `nil` in cocoa collections. If you use the conditional operator, there is an extension that lets you shorten the code somewhat (see [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5471573/335858)).

Comment: This is what I finally did (see updated question above), which works (at least keeps the app from crashing; I'll check on the method's side for empty key.  Thank you for your time.

Comment: @spokane-dude You should also have a look at the other answer, it *actually* answers your question.

Answer (score 5):

It is not possible with a pure NSMutableDictionary, and in most cases you want to convert nil values into `[NSNull null]` or just omit them from the dictionary. Sometimes (very seldom), though, it is convenient to allow nil values, and in those cases you can use CFMutableDictionary with custom callbacks.

If you go this way, I recommend that you use CoreFoundation API for all accesses, e.g. `CFDictionarySetValue` and `CFDictionaryGetValue`.

However, if you know what you're doing, you can use toll-free bridging and cast that CFMutableDictionary to NSMutableDictionary or NSDictionary. This may be useful if you have a bunch of helpers that accept NSDictionary, and you want to use them on your modified nil-capable dictionary. (Of course, make sure that the helpers aren't surprised by nil values.)

If you do the bridging, note that:

1) NSMutableDictionary setter raises errors on nil values before bridging, so you need to use CFDictionarySetValue to set values that are potentially nil.

2) technically, we're violating a contract of NSMutableDictionary here, and things may break (e.g. in future OS updates)

3) a lot of code will be very surprised to find nil values in a dictionary; you should only pass the bridged frankendictionaries to the code that you control

See [ridiculousfish's post on toll-free bridging](http://ridiculousfish.com/blog/posts/bridge.html) for an explanation of why a bridged CFDictionary behaves differently from NSDictionary.

Example:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

const void *NullSafeRetain(CFAllocatorRef allocator, const void *value) {
    return value ? CFRetain(value) : NULL;
}
void NullSafeRelease(CFAllocatorRef allocator, const void *value) {
    if (value)
        CFRelease(value);
}
const CFDictionaryValueCallBacks kDictionaryValueCallBacksAllowingNULL = {
    .version = 0,
    .retain = NullSafeRetain,
    .release = NullSafeRelease,
    .copyDescription = CFCopyDescription,
    .equal = CFEqual,
};

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        CFMutableDictionaryRef cfdictionary = CFDictionaryCreateMutable(NULL, 0, &kCFTypeDictionaryKeyCallBacks, &kDictionaryValueCallBacksAllowingNULL);
        CFDictionarySetValue(cfdictionary, @"foo", @"bar");
        CFDictionarySetValue(cfdictionary, @"boz", nil);

        NSMutableDictionary *dictionary = CFBridgingRelease(cfdictionary);
        NSLog(@"dictionary[foo] = %@", dictionary[@"foo"]);
        NSLog(@"dictionary[foo] = %@", dictionary[[@"fo" stringByAppendingString:@"o"]]);
        NSLog(@"dictionary[boz] = %@", dictionary[@"boz"]);
        NSLog(@"dictionary = %@", dictionary);
        NSLog(@"(dictionary isEqualTo: dictionary) = %d", [dictionary isEqualToDictionary:dictionary]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

outputs:

```
dictionary[foo] = bar
dictionary[foo] = bar
dictionary[boz] = (null)
dictionary = {
    boz = (null);
    foo = bar;
}
(dictionary isEqualTo: dictionary) = 1
```

Comment: CFEqual will crash with NULL parameters; your example might work if external code checks pointer equality before calling that function, but if you were to create a copy of the dictionary above but set the boz key to a valid value, then compare the two dictionaries, I believe it will crash instead of returning false.  You need a null-safe wrapper for CFEqual to assign to the ValueCallBacks property, I think.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to set a `NSDictionary` value to one that may or may not be set yet from `NSUserDefaults`.

What I did was wrap the values in a `stringwithFormat` call. Both values are not yet set so start as null. When I run without the `stringwithFormat` call the app crashes. So I did this and in my situation worked.

```
-(NSDictionary*)userDetailsDict{
NSDictionary* userDetails = @{
                              @"userLine":[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]stringForKey:kSelectedLine] ],
                              @"userDepot":[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]stringForKey:@"kSelected Duty Book"]]
                              };

return userDetails;
}
```

Comment: I believe this is just transposing `nil` values to an empty string. You could also do `value ?: @""` (which is short-hand for `value ? value : @""`.