# Find Existence of Key in NSDictionary

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsdictionary, nsmutabledictionary

How can we identify the object is available for a particular key. I have tried following:

```
for(NSDictionary *item in jsonArray){
if([item objectForKey:@"EventDate"])
        NSLog([item objectForKey:@"EventDate"]);
}
```

This is getting crash the code with error:

```
  -[__NSCFString objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6a567b0
```

I have also find many posts that is showing `objectForKey` will return `nil` if a key doesn't exists. Than my question is there is also a method in `NSDictionary` class that is "setNilValueForKey". How is this possible that we cannot specify the `NSDictionary` key with nil object and also we have the method to set nil value for object in `NSDictionary`.

Please Suggest on first and also make me clear on second query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Your jsonArray contains other types of objects than `NSDictionaries`, including at least one `NSString`. `NSString` doesn't respond to objectForKey: so it throws an exception when you try to call it. You'll have to look at the JSON to determine how to proceed with whatever you were doing.

2) There is an `NSObject` method `setNilValueForKey:` which is related to key-value coding. This isn't really related to `NSDictionary`. If you really need to represent nil in your dictionary, set `[NSNull null]` as the object for your key that represents nil.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for responding 1. It working correctly when we have the object with specified key.   2. If it is the case I have tried with this too as if([[item objectForKey:@""]isEqual:[NSNull null]]). It is crashing too.

Comment: So what objects cause the crash then?

Comment: You have suggested correctly for both queries. Changing the array response is working.

Answer (score 1):

item is not a NSDictionary its a String. So check your jsonArray it may be contains only strings not dictinaries

Comment: It is working perfectly when we are getting value with respective key. It is just crashing when we have not the object with specified key.

Answer (score 1):

Not all the objects in your array are dictionaries. You need to check what kind of data you're processing before you work on it. Something like this:

```
for(NSObject* item in jsonArray) {
  if ([item isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
    // do dictionary stuff
  }
  else if ([item isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]) {
    // do string stuff
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Answer to second query**

There is a non-nil object called NSNull that is built specifically to represent nils in situations where "plain" nil is not acceptable. If you replace your nils with **[NSNull null]** object, **NSDictionary will take them**. You would need to check for NSNull on the way out, though.

Refer more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10856753/how-to-allow-nsmutabledictionary-to-accept-nil-value-as-a-key-object)

**Answer to first query**

```
for(id *item in jsonArray)
{
  if([item isKindofClass:[NSDictionary class])
  {
    NSArray *allKeys = [item allKeys];
    for(NSString *strKey in allKeys)
    {
     if([strKey isEqualToString:@"EventDate"])
     {
       // EventDate key has object
       NSLog([item objectForKey:@"EventDate"]);
     }
    }
  }
}
```